# Grunt Sass - Multiple css style outputs

Tags: javascript, css, sass

I've done a fair bit of searching but can't seem to come up with a full answer to this.

I'm using grunt to manage my sass flow and I've been trying to find a way to output multiple css styles from grunt.

For example:

base.scss should have two outputs the first being style.css which has the expanded css style.

The second should be style.min.css which has the compressed css style.

How can I configure my gruntfile to do this for me?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this by having two configurations, one outputting expanded CSS and the other compressed. Then register your task to run both.  Your grunt file should look something like this:

**Example**

```js
module.exports = function(grunt) {
    'use strict';
    grunt.initConfig({
        pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
        // Sass
        sass: {
            dev: { // This outputs the expanded css file
                files: {
                    'style.css': 'base.scss'
                }
            },
            prod: { // This outputs the compressed css file
                options: {
                    outputStyle: 'compressed' // Minify output
                },
                files: {
                    'style.min.css': 'base.scss'
                }
            }
        }
    });

    grunt.registerTask('default', ['sass:dev', 'sass:prod']); // Task runs both
}
```

Comment: Worked perfectly, thank you very much this is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @Duncan Actually you can just use ['sass'] and grunt will automatically start both 'sass:dev' and 'sass:prod' tasks.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a more complete solution of what belongs in `gruntfile.js`, improving upon what Colin Bacon has already posted.  By default grunt's `pkg` is already set to read `package.json` in the current directory, so no need to write that.  You just need to install the jit-grunt plugin (besides the watch and sass plugins of course) to get my answer working.

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
require('jit-grunt')(grunt);

grunt.initConfig({
  sass: {
      expanded: {                         // Target
        options: {                       // Target options
          style: 'expanded'
        },
        files: {                         // Dictionary of files
          'style.css': 'style.scss'       // 'destination': 'source'
        }
      },
      compressed: {                         // Target
        options: {                       // Target options
          style: 'compressed'
        },
        files: {                         // Dictionary of files
          'style.min.css': 'style.scss'  // 'destination': 'source'
        }
      }
  },
  watch: {
    styles: {
      files: ['**/*.scss'], // which files to watch
      tasks: ['sass'],
      options: {
        spawn: false // speeds up watch reaction
      }
    }
  }
});

grunt.registerTask('default', ['sass', 'watch']);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add a new manifest file in your styles folder. For example, you have normally `main.scss`, if you create `main2.scss` and import some files in there. It will create a file for each manifest file you have.

If your `sass` task looks something like this (default yeoman webapp generator):

```
sass: {
  options: {
    sourceMap: true,
    includePaths: ['bower_components']
    },
  dist: {
    files: [{
      expand: true,
      cwd: '<%= config.app %>/styles',
      src: ['*.{scss,sass}'],
      dest: '.tmp/styles',
      ext: '.css'
    }]
  },
  server: {
    files: [{
      expand: true,
      cwd: '<%= config.app %>/styles',
      src: ['*.{scss,sass}'],
      dest: '.tmp/styles',
      ext: '.css'
    }]
  }
}
```

The file section sass read all `.scss/.sass` files and copy those to `.tmp/styles`. Later, `copy` task move those to `dist/styles`.

Comment: I'll give it a shot, is there no way of doing without creating a new .scss file?

Comment: @Duncan using grunt-sass, I don't know a way of doing it.